# Verilog reg assignment?

Tags: verilog

I'm totally new to Verilog programming and I do not understand where to initialize `reg` variables?

Let's have a look at the following snippets:
Edit:
[Warning at synthesize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifLMB.png)

```
module test (
       output LED0 
       );   
reg led = 1'b1;
assign LED0 = led;
endmodule
```

or

```
module test (
       output LED0 
       );   

reg led;
initial begin
    reg led <= 1'b1;
end

assign LED0 = led;
endmodule
```

Give me: Using initial value of led since it is never assigned at the line: `reg led = 1'b1;`

Are `reg` types only assigned in always@ block?

Another example:

```
module fourBitCounter
       (input clk,
        output [3:0]counter
        );

wire clk;
initial begin
reg[3:0] counter = 4'b1;
end

always@ (posedge clk) begin

         if(counter > 15)
              counter <= 0;
         else
              counter <= counter + 1;
         end endmodule
```

Here the reg has an initial value of 0 but I've set it before to 1... What's wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are reg types only assigned in always@ block?

No, `reg` types can be assigned in `always` blocks and `initial` blocks (plus `task` and `function` but I'll skip them in the scope of this question)

For your `fourBitCounter`, the `reg[3:0] counter` declared in the `initial` block creates a local variable also called `counter` that is only accessible within the scope of the block it was created in. You need to remove the `reg[3:0]` in the initial block so that the assignment get applied the the intended `counter`. But it will still not work because you declared `counter` as an inferred wire type and `always`/`initial` blocks cannot assign wires.

`counter` was declared as an output of a 4-bit inferred wire (`output [3:0] counter` is synonyms to `output wire [3:0] counter`). Since `counter` is assigned in an `always` block and `initial` block it needs to be a `reg` type. Therefore it should be declared as `output reg [3:0] counter`.

Also, you declared `clk` as in input and as a local wire, it cannot be both. Ports can be accessed locally, there is no reason to re-declare them as local nets.

FYI: for a 4-bit value, 15+1 equals 0 because there is nothing to store the MSB.

```
module fourBitCounter (
    input clk,
    output reg [3:0] counter // 'output reg', not 'output'
  );

//wire clk; // do not do this, clk is an input
initial begin
  counter = 4'b1; // no 'reg' here
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(counter > 15) // this will never evaluate as true with counter declared as 4-bit
    counter <= 0;
  else
    counter <= counter + 1;
end
endmodule
```

For Verilog, `assign` statements can only be applied on net types (e.g. `wire`). This is legal:

```
module test ( output LED0 ); // LED0 is an inferred wire
assign LED0 = 1'b1;
endmodule
```

This is illegal:

```
module test ( output reg LED0 ); // Explicit reg
assign LED0 = 1'b1; // illegal, assign on a reg
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me to fix my wrong mistakes, yet I have one more question: Why you used a non-assignment inside a procedural block? Why not: counter <= 4'b1. P.S. counter is still 0 at the beginning, maybe initial block is not synthesizable?

Comment: In the initial block I used a a blocking assignment (`=`). In the always block I used a non-blocking assignment (`<=`), this should used to assign intended flops/latches in always blocks. I could have used non-blocking in the initial block but I typically don't with my coding style. Non-blocking postpones the update in the scheduler which is useful on clock edges but not at time zero

Comment: All makes sense now except the following: Can I Assign a reg to a wire, like in my very first example? What is wrong there? Even if I did assign the led inside initial block, I would still get: Using initial value of led since it is never assigned

Comment: I could of course assign directly LED0 to 1, but I wanted to see if it possible to assign a reg to a wire. Please take a look at the picture from my first post I uploaded. Thank you so much for your time! All of you!

Comment: The issue with `led` is a synthesis warning. Except for ROMs, it is not common to initialize a reg and then never updated it. It is legal, but usually unintentional as it is more likely a bug or incomplete code; hence it being a warning. I recommend resolving as many warnings as possible; it  makes debugging a little easier when trying to figure out what went wrong when the design doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it satisfies your question. It lets others know an acceptable solution be found.

Answer (score 0):

From your first code sample:

```
reg led;             // <-- This declares one register called "led"
initial begin
    reg led <= 1'b1; // <-- This declares a *separate* register called "led"
end                  //     which is only valid in the initial block
```

The same issue exists in your second sample; you're declaring a separate register in the `initial` block. Don't use the keywords `reg` or `wire` if you're just trying to assign a value.

Comment: Yes, indeed I made a mistake. But even without the reg or wire in front of the variable name does not make it work. How about my first example?